# Getting actual size of struct

Tags: c++, winapi, struct

I have a function which requires me to pass a pointer `LPVOID` and a size `DWORD`

these values will be used by `VirtualAllocEx`.

How can I get the full actual size of my `struct`?

Struct:

```
typedef struct CLRStartUpInfo
{
    LPCSTR pwzLibrary;
    LPCSTR pwzTypeName;
    LPCSTR pwzEntryPoint;
    LPCSTR pwzArgument;
} CLRStartUpInfo, *PCLRStartUpInfo;
```

Function I am calling:

```
HRESULT CallRemoteFunction(HANDLE hProcess, LPVOID lpFunction, LPVOID lpParameter, DWORD dwParameterSize)
```

Comment: *How can I get the full actual size of my struct?* - I suggest typing that into Google. I got results.

Comment: sizeof(CLRStartUpInfo) doesn't work fine?

Comment: Or `sizeof CLRStartUpInfo`? Parentheses aren't necessary @wuqiang.

Comment: You want to know how to get the **size of** your structure, and didn't find a result on Google? (Or a clue from **size of** that might lead you to a search of the documentation for **size** that would have led you to **sizeof()**?)

Comment: Note that the size of the structure is only the tip of the iceberg. You also have to marshal the pointed-to strings.

Comment: Another part of the iceberg is that the structure size needs to match the bitness of the target process, not the source process.

Answer (score -1):

You can get it using `sizeof(CLRStartUpInfo)`. Windows OS  add padding bytes to struct if it is not multiple of 4 (32 bit). So if your actual struct size is 7, it will add 1 byte and make it 8.

To avoid that you can use `#pragma pack (1)`, it will restrict padding.

Comment: This is not true. A struct containing 7 chars has no padding and size 7. One also wonders how your answer relates to the question. Did you mean to write a comment?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have written this program.

struct s 
{
 int a;
 char b,c,d;
} c;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 printf("Size of c %d",sizeof(c));
 return 0;
}

--> it gives output as 8

Comment: That's lovely. Try ` struct s { char c1; } c; int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { printf("Size of c %d",sizeof(c)); return 0; } and see what the output is. It's almost as if you didn't read my comment. I don't think you know how alignment works on Windows.

Comment: That's new for me. I thought I knew it, but I need to study it. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score -1):

The pragma preprocessor command can be used to pack things to byte boundaries. Anything you attempt to do to change the packing would have to be done with precompiler directives that are environment specific. Different compilers have different rules for packing.

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct test
{
    char ch; // 1 byte
    int i;  // 4 bytes
}sample1, sample2;
#pragma pack
// Here is a complete function that compiles
int main()
{
    std::cout << "sizeof(sample1)" << sizeof(sample1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I found this with a simple google search. Here is MSDN's page. Just make sure that you read the warnings carefully. After you manually pack, there are sometimes alignment problems that can be tricky to understand. I don't fully understand the issues myself.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1(VS.80).aspx

Comment: How does this relate to the question?